# Matplot lib unstable after using annotate

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I am wondering if someone can spot what I may have done wrong to cause this somewhat unstable behaviour in my plot in Jupyter Labs.

I am annotating shapely points on a map, using the following code:

```
ax = gdf_2[gdf_2['Zone'] == 'ULEZ'].plot()

gdf_2.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(s=x.pod_id_location, xy=x.loc['geometry'].coords[0]), axis=1)

ctx.add_basemap(ax=ax)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

For some reason, whilst this does produce my plot, it prints tiny in the notebook. If I try to increase the figure size, I sometimes get a warning that I am overstepping the pixel limit, and other times it causes my kernel to die. This is what my plot looks like, and below is my data behind it.

[image]

```
pod_id_location geometry    Zone
0   1245    POINT (-22993.152 6728924.970)  non-ULEZ
7940    2245    POINT (-13406.652 6714132.654)  ULEZ
13934   3245    POINT (-16958.244 6720147.066)  non-ULEZ
25068   5245    POINT (-20791.698 6699568.057)  non-ULEZ
32551   6245    POINT (-40049.413 6704610.464)  non-ULEZ
... ... ... ...
849223  742451  POINT (-12923.302 6720129.538)  non-ULEZ
849547  832450  POINT (-6445.287 6717978.299)   non-ULEZ
851190  872450  POINT (-4064.943 6697346.893)   non-ULEZ
852852  892450  POINT (6744.514 6713063.033)    non-ULEZ
853523  982450  POINT (-958.349 6706975.535)    non-ULEZ
```

Comment: I suppose you are annotating points, which are way outside the map. (E.g. if the map shows the city of London, but you annotate a point in Oxford, it would make the figure grow massively)

Comment: oh crap of course! I was filtering the points in the map in the code by didnt filter the dataframe itself! Thanks, its getting late and i am clearly getting tired...